# Transformations of Radical Functions

Tags: functions

This would make $y=\sqrt{9(x-3)}$ equal to $y=3\sqrt{(x-3)}$, which would mean that there is a vertical expansion by a factor of $3$, and a translation of $3$ units right?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you got that right. Alternatively, you can transform $3$ units to the right first and then scale vertically by $3$.

[image]